# Intellij CE auto-completion and error highlighting don't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, syntax-highlighting

I have installed Intellij 2022 CE and I faced a problem with Java mistake's highlighting.
Code auto-completing doesn't work too.
In top right corner I see title "analyzing".

I found information that it is necessary to mark folder with code as "resource folder" and I did it. Nothing helped.

Any ideas what to do?

Here is the example of errors without highlighting

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a new IntelliJ plugin, but did not follow https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/creating-plugin-project.html

Comment: Try to temporarily [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) all third-party plugins and clear the IDE caches. (File | Invalidate Caches... | Invalidate and Restart)

Comment: If the problem remains submit a new request at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: I installed older Intelij version (2020) and it solved my problem :)